# How do I get the intro text to appear in my public dev. story profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, developer-story

When I'm editing my story I can see my intro text, as below:

[image]

However, on my public profile it doesn't display:

[image]

Is there something I'm not doing to that I need to do to get it to appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I missed the `Only show your personal statement to employers` checkbox that appears when editing that section. Once I un-ticked that the intro text was displayed.